# Why "beat around the bush?"

Tags: etymology

I personally find the term "beat around the bush weird", where did it originate from?

Comment: I have not heard this with "build" in place of "beat".

Comment: Sorry it was a typo

Answer (score 3):

Beaters are servants employed to flush out game birds to be shot. There's an early example cited here http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/beat-around-the-bush.html

"He bet about the bush, whyles other caught the birds." (George Gascoigne's Works, 1572)

Comment: So 'beating around the bush' had a purpose to it. How did it come to mean avoid coming to the point?